# c++ hashtable where keys are strings and values are vectors of strings

Tags: c++, string, data-structures, hashtable, lookup

I have a large collection of unique strings (about 500k).  Each string is associated with a vector of strings.  I'm currently storing this data in a

```
map<string, vector<string> >
```

and it's working fine.  However I'd like the look-up into the map to be faster than log(n).  Under these constrained circumstances how can I create a hashtable that supports O(1) look-up?  Seems like this should be possible since I know all the keys ahead of time... and all the keys are unique (so I don't have to account for collisions).

Cheers!

Comment: A perfect hash should help increase speeds. Sounds like you have all of the prerequisites http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perfect_hash_function

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create a hashtable with `boost::unordered_map`, `std::tr1::unordered_map` or (on C++0x compilers) `std::unordered_map`. That takes almost zero effort. [Google sparsehash](http://code.google.com/p/google-sparsehash/) may be faster still and tends to take less memory. (Deletion can be a pain, but it seems you won't need that.)

If the code is still not fast enough, you can exploit prior knowledge of the keys with a minimal perfect hash, as suggested by others, to obtain guaranteed O(1) performance. Whether the code generating effort that takes is worth it depends on you; putting 500k keys into a tool like `gperf` may take a code generator generator.

You may also want to look at [CMPH](http://cmph.sourceforge.net/), which generates a perfect hash function at run-time, though through a C API.

Comment: With Google Sparsehash or [MCT](https://launchpad.net/libmct/) _and_ without C++0x for move constructors you need to be careful with rehashing.  Basically, each rehashing will result in moving the internal data array, which, before C++0x, uses *copying* and thus can be very slow for vectors.

Answer (score 2):

I would look into creating a [Perfect Hash Function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perfect_hash_function) for your table. This will guarantee no collisions which are an expensive operation to resolve. [Perfect Hash Function Generators](http://www.gnu.org/software/gperf/) are also available.

Answer (score 2):

What you're looking for is a [Perfect Hash](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perfect_hash). [gperf](http://www.gnu.org/software/gperf/) is often used to generate these, but I don't know how well it works with such a large collection of strings.

Comment: `gperf` is somewhat limited when you get into huge collections as it outputs somewhat static C code for the hasher. I've used it with ~2k entries without any fuss. No idea about 500k.

Answer (score 2):

If you want no collisions for a known collection of keys you're looking for a [perfect hash](http://cmph.sourceforge.net/concepts.html). The [CMPH library](http://cmph.sourceforge.net/) (my apologies as it is for C rather than C++) is mature and can generate minimal perfect hashes for rather large data sets.

Comment: CMPH looks interesting, particularly that statement *"billion of keys"*. I wonder how hard it would be to export the generated hash function?

Comment: @Mark: It outputs a file which encodes it, you likely could "back it out" into a giant `.c` file.